# C# Selenium get Html document after it has been modified

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Basically I have the following HTML source:

```
<b class="number"> Click to see </b>
```

And when you click on this, this is its JS code:

```
function fun(){
   number.html("12345");
}
```

Now, thanks to `driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`  I am able to show the number, but when I execute `driver.PageSource();`, in the Html document I keep seeing "Click to see" rather than "12345". How to overcome this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to get the current outerHTML:

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var newHtml = js.ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
```